# Customizing authentication exceptions spring oauth

Tags: oauth, spring-security, jersey

I'm using **jersey** as a RESTFul webserver. (jersey-server 1.8) with spring (3.2.0.RELEASE) and hibernate.
My endpoints are protected using spring-security (3.1.3.RELEASE) with 2 legged oAuth 1.0a (spring-security-oauth 1.0.0.M4 )

Everything works as expected and the securing works.
Inside my ConsumerDetailsServiceImpl (implements ConsumerDetailsService, UserDetailsService, AuthenticationProvider) i throw different exceptions (all are of form OAuthException now, but i want to add my own custom exceptions)

However no matter what i tried i cannot get to customize the different authentication and access denied exceptions the way i want, i always get the default 401 page

My API is agreed to always return a json responseobject so i need to catch these exceptions and show 401 pages with json inside it

My securty.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:oauth="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/oauth"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/oauth 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-oauth.xsd">


<!-- Authentication beans -->
<bean name="consumerDetailsService" class="com.securitytest.core.services.impl.ConsumerDetailsServiceImpl" />
<bean name="oauthProcessingFilterEntryPoint" class="org.springframework.security.oauth.provider.OAuthProcessingFilterEntryPoint" />
<bean id="oAuthAuthenticationHandler" class="com.securitytest.core.security.CustomOAuthAuthenticationHandler" />

<security:http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true" entry-point-ref="oauthProcessingFilterEntryPoint" >
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/rest/secured/**" access="isAuthenticated()" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/rest/unsecured/**" access="permitAll" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/rest/**" access="isAuthenticated()" />
    <security:form-login login-page='/login' default-target-url="/home"  authentication-failure-handler-ref="authenticationFailureHandler"/>
    <security:access-denied-handler ref="accessDeniedHandler" />
</security:http>

<bean id="accessDeniedHandler" class="com.securitytest.core.security.CustomoauthAccessDeniedHandler" />
  <!-- this was just a test, it didn't work obviously -->  
<bean id="authenticationFailureHandler"              class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.ExceptionMappingAuthenticationFailureHandler">
    <property name="exceptionMappings">
        <props>
            <prop key="org.springframework.security.authentication.BadCredentialsException">/login/badCredentials</prop>
            <prop key="org.springframework.security.authentication.CredentialsExpiredException">/login/credentialsExpired</prop>
            <prop key="org.springframework.security.authentication.LockedException">/login/accountLocked</prop>
            <prop key="org.springframework.security.authentication.DisabledException">/login/accountDisabled</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<security:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
    <security:authentication-provider ref="consumerDetailsService" />
</security:authentication-manager>

<bean id="nonceServices" class="org.springframework.security.oauth.provider.nonce.InMemoryNonceServices" />

<oauth:provider 
        auth-handler-ref="oAuthAuthenticationHandler" 
        consumer-details-service-ref="consumerDetailsService" 
        nonce-services-ref="nonceServices" 
        token-services-ref="tokenServices"
        require10a="true"

        />
<oauth:token-services id="tokenServices" />
```

### Stuff i tried

1. Change the exceptionTranslationFilter -> is not allowed by the docs
2. Add a custom access-denied-handler and a authentication-failure-handler-ref

   ```
   <security:http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true" entry-point-ref="oauthProcessingFilterEntryPoint" >
      <security:intercept-url pattern="/rest/secured/**" access="isAuthenticated()" />
      <security:intercept-url pattern="/rest/unsecured/**" access="permitAll" />
      <security:intercept-url pattern="/rest/**" access="isAuthenticated()" />
      <security:form-login login-page='/login' default-target-url="/home"  authentication-failure-handler-ref="authenticationFailureHandler"/>

      <security:access-denied-handler ref="accessDeniedHandler" />
   </security:http>
   ```

   -> this gets blatantly ignored by spring-security/oauth
3. Add a custom filter after the EXCEPTION_TRANSLATION_FILTER

   ```
   <security:custom-filter after="EXCEPTION_TRANSLATION_FILTER" ref="myFilter" />
   ```

   MyFilter just implements "javax.servlet.Filter". 
   -> It goes into the doFilter but i have no idea what do with it (i can't see which exception is thrown, if any).

Any help is appreciated!!

Answer (score 0):

I am quite late answering this question and you might have resolved or moved to some other alternative. However I recently dived into the Oauth and faced similar problem and managed to resolve it. Sharing it as reference for others.

I have used Oauth's MediaTypeAwareAccessDeniedHandler and MediaTypeAwareAuthenticationEntryPoint for error handling. As per documentation, it defaults to 401 error page. However, from source code, error response content type is dependent upon request Accept-Type. But requesting clients to always sent Accept-Type as application/json is like asking fox to safeguard hen.

Good news is that response type support setter injection. So simple solution was to override defaults and inject response property to always sent JSON response irrespective of Accept-Type

```
<bean id="accessDeniedHandler" class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.error.MediaTypeAwareAccessDeniedHandle"/>
   <property name="responses">
     <map> 
       <entry key="*/*" value="{error:&quot;%s&quot;}"></entry>
     </map>
   </property>
 </bean>
```